# Example of Group which is not a direct product of its Sylow-Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can you please give me an example of a group which could not be written as the direct product of its Sylow-subgroups?

Comment: Any finite non-nilpotent group makes the cut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The minimal example is the symmetric group $S_3$.